# Is it possible to sync files (bidirectionally) from a local file server to an online SharePoint site? (SharePoint Online/O365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, synchronization

I'm using SharePoint Online through O365 to admin a small site that has a decent-sized (50+ files, but only about ~2GB in filesize) document library.

The team in question will frequently collaborate on creating and making changes to various files on a local fileserver, and then upload the finished documents to the SharePoint Online site.

Moving forward, I want all changes made to be in SharePoint Online alone, but at the current time I don't think that's going to happen. As a workaround, I would like to have files synchronized between the local fileshare and the online site.

Is it possible to enable a bidirectional sync between the SharePoint Online site and the local fileshare?

I've seen some talk about doing this with OneDrive, but from what I can tell that will only work to sync individual users' OneDrive accounts with the SP site, which isn't really what I want to do.

Is this even possible anymore? (Or was it ever?) I seem to remember this being a thing in 2013/2014 but can't find anything about it.